# How to use docker remote api to create container?

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker. I have read the [tutorial](http://docs.docker.com/reference/api/docker_remote_api_v1.19/) in docker remote API . In aspect of creating container. It show me too many param to fill. I want to know what is equivalent to this command :

> docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --restart=always --name registry
>   registry:2.

I have no idea about it. Can anyone tell me? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Original answer (July 2015):

That would be (not tested directly), as [in this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150311015410/http://blog.flux7.com/blogs/docker/docker-tutorial-series-part-8-docker-remote-api) (provided the [remote API is enabled](http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/07/quick-tip-how-to-enable-docker-remote-api.html)):

First create the container:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"Image": " registry:2.",}' http://localhost:2376/containers/create?name=registry
```

Then start it:

```
curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"PortBindings": { "5000/tcp": [{ "HostPort": "5000" }] },"RestartPolicy": { "Name": "always",},}' http://localhost:2376/containers/registry/start?name=registry
```

---

Update February 2017, for docker 1.13+ see [rocksteady](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4790497/rocksteady)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42361766/6309), using a similar idea but with the current [engine/api/v1.26](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.26/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have succeed.

Comment: I use HttpClient in java to connect api, add param that you show, it return me error about "invalid character 'I' looking for beginning of value", why? I update my question.

Comment: @v11 considering you mentioned that you had succeeded before, could you make that a new question? That will allow other to use this one for curl. It didn't mention the java API initially.

Answer (score 5):

More or less just copying [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc)s answer in order to update to todays version of [docker (**1.13**)](https://blog.docker.com/2017/01/whats-new-in-docker-1-13/) and [docker remote api version (**v1.26**)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.26/).

**What is different:**

- All the configuration needs to be done when the container is created, otherwise the following error message is returned when starting the container the way [VonC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6309/vonc) did.

  `{"message":"starting container with non-empty request body was deprecated since v1.10 and removed in v1.12"}`

---

**First create the container:** *(including all the configuration)*

`curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @docker.conf http://localhost:2376/containers/create?name=registry`

The file `docker.conf` looks like this:

```
{
  "Image": registry:2.",
  "ExposedPorts": {
    "5000/tcp": {}
  },
  "HostConfig": {
    "PortBindings": {
      "5000/tcp": [
        {
          "HostPort": "5000"
        }
      ]
    },
    "RestartPolicy": {
      "Name": "always"
    }
    "AutoRemove": true
  }
}
```

**Then start it:** *(the parameter **name** is not necessary, the container is just named **registry**)*

`curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:2376/containers/registry/start`

Comment: Helpful answer in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

**Create docker container in Docker Engine v1.24**

Execute the post request -

```
 curl -X POST  -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://DOCKER_SERVER_HOST:DOCKER_PORT/v1.24/containers/create?name=containername
```

In the request body, you can specify the JSON parameters like

```
{
        "Hostname": "172.x.x.x",
        "Image": "docker-image-name",
        "Volumes": "",
        "Entrypoint": "",
        "Tty": true
}
```

It creates your docker container

**Start the container**

Execute the POST request

```
curl -X POST  http://DOCKER_SERVER_HOST:DOCKER_PORT/v1.24/containers/containername/start
```

Reference link - https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/