# Enable Docker Remote API - raspberry pi / raspbian

Tags: docker, raspberry-pi, remoteapi

My starting point is:

- [How to use docker remote api to create container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381978/how-to-use-docker-remote-api-to-create-container),

so I edit `/etc/init/docker.conf` and update 2 occurrences  of the **DOCKER_OPTS** variable to:

`DOCKER_OPTS='-H tcp://0.0.0.0:4243 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock'`

Then, a simple test to list docker images fails:

```
$ service docker restart
$ curl -X GET http://10.143.0.218:4243/images/json
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.143.0.218 port 4243: Connection refused
```

Docker version is:

```
$ sudo docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 19:06:36 2016
OS/Arch:      linux/arm

Server:
 Version:      1.12.3
 API version:  1.24
 Go version:   go1.6.3
 Git commit:   6b644ec
 Built:        Wed Oct 26 19:06:36 2016
 OS/Arch:      linux/arm
```

Comment: What OS are you using on the RPi?

Comment: Raspbian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested this, but if it's Jessie, then it uses systemd by default as the init system iirc, and this has implications for how the daemon (`dockerd`) is configured and started.

So you're editing the `/etc/init/docker.conf` file but I don't think that's being read / used.

Take a read of [this article on different startup procedures](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/) on each init system in Docker, and [this for specific systemd configuration](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/).

Answer (score 8):

The solution comes from the comments of this page: http://www.virtuallyghetto.com/2014/07/quick-tip-how-to-enable-docker-remote-api.html

> [08/18/2016 at 6:00 am]    Oliver Weise says: 
>      Thanks, that put me in the right direction. However since Ubuntu 16.04
>       with its systemd docker daemon the `/etc/default/docker` is no longer
>       effective. Instead you need to create a systemd dropin file.
>
> I placed such a file under: `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/remote-api.conf`
>
> With the contents:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H tcp://127.0.0.1:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock
```

> (Yes, the double ExecStart is necessary)
>
> After that run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload // reloading daemon definitions
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

Comment: Isn't this basically my answer?

Comment: ^ No. Your answer was to go read a bunch of docs that apparently didn't clearly answer the question. :-)

Comment: This is probably the correct answer, but for me I was unable to get the API working without actually editing /lib/systems/system/docker.service directly. No matter what I put in a drop-in file, the service would pick it up but the API would only be bound to the daemon socket. The drop-in method is probably the best way to go, and perhaps the reason it wasn't a success was the method to install docker> I used: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-easy-way-to-set-up-docker-on-a-raspberry-pi-7d24ced073ef and have had no issues otherwise.

Comment: mine was located at /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service and i only updated the tcp line.  raspbian