# How to get and present docker states inside html page by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, docker, continuous-integration, devops

I want to GET and present the web service states inside HTML dashboard.
What is the most friendly and easy way to do it by JavaScript?

For example - When some docker is stopped i want to present a red led icon and when the response take long i want to present a yellow led icon and if it's ok.. you guess right, I want to present a green led icon.

Please your pro assistance.
Thanks.

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/portainer/portainer This is an docker adminpanel running in your browser. Maybe you can copy some code and learn how to get the running containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use the API provided by docker, see [Docker Engine API (v1.26)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.26/)

`GET /containers/json` will give you back the details you want in json format.

```
function getContainers(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url:  '/containers/json?all=1',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
          if( callback ) callback(data);
        },
        error: function(err)
        {
          // ...
        },
        timeout: 30000
    });
}
```

Also:

- Maybe you want to take a look at this: [How to use docker remote api to create container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381978/how-to-use-docker-remote-api-to-create-container)
- At the time I was doing tests similar to what you are trying to do, I had to enable this "Docker Remote API", see: [Enable Docker Remote API - raspberry pi / raspbian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591356/enable-docker-remote-api-raspberry-pi-raspbian?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- My approach: https://github.com/tgogos/rpi_docker_ui