# error when setting up remote docker server

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, docker-machine, mern, vscode-remote

On my Pi I followed [this tutorial](https://www.docker.com/blog/happy-pi-day-docker-raspberry-pi/) to install docker on raspbian.  Few side notes here:

1. I did NOT setup a swarm, I stopped at docker info and (as in other guides) I succesfully ran the hello world container.
2. idk if it matters, but this guide (unlike others) had me edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and add line: `deb https://download.docker.com/linux/raspbian/ stretch stable`

On my develop machine (win 10) I used [this tutorial](https://dev.to/sujaykundu777/utilizing-the-power-of-docker-while-building-mern-apps-using-mern-docker-4olb) to add docker configs and ymls to my mern stack app.  However at multiple points in this tutorial they wanted me to run docker commands, so I ended up having to install Docker Desktop.

But I don't want to use local containers, I want to use the remote one on my Pi.  So I used [this tutorial](https://www.kevinkuszyk.com/2016/11/28/connect-your-docker-client-to-a-remote-docker-host/) to try and setup my remote docker.

However Im getting an error:

> C:\Users\oweng>docker-machine create --driver generic
> --generic-ip-address=192.168.1.2 --generic-ssh-key "%HOMEPATH%/.ssh/id_rsa" --generic-ssh-user=pi remote-docker-host
> Running pre-create checks... Creating machine... (remote-docker-host)
> Importing SSH key... Waiting for machine to be running, this may take
> a few minutes... Detecting operating system of created instance...
> Waiting for SSH to be available... Enter passphrase for key
> 'C:\Users\oweng.docker\machine\machines\remote-docker-host\id_rsa':
> Enter passphrase for key
> 'C:\Users\oweng.docker\machine\machines\remote-docker-host\id_rsa':
> Detecting the provisioner... Enter passphrase for key
> 'C:\Users\oweng.docker\machine\machines\remote-docker-host\id_rsa':
> **Error creating machine: Error detecting OS: OS type not recognized**

I have googled the error a bit but havnt found a solution.

furthermore when checking listening ports on my Pi (docker server) I dont see it running

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN xrdp-sesm  390
> root    7u  IPv6  14566      0t0  TCP [::1]:3350 (LISTEN) sshd
> 404  root    3u  IPv4  17224      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN) sshd
> 404  root    4u  IPv6  17226      0t0  TCP *:22 (LISTEN) xrdp
> 406  xrdp   11u  IPv6  17302      0t0  TCP *:3389 (LISTEN)

So I feel like maybe the server is not running?  But it seems to be.

> pi@raspberrypi:~ $ systemctl status docker ● docker.service - Docker
> Application Container Engine    Loaded: loaded
> (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
> Active: active (running) since Tue 2020-11-03 07:18:21 PST; 3h 35min
> ago
> Docs: https://docs.docker.com  Main PID: 496 (dockerd)
> Tasks: 13    CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
> └─496 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
>
> Nov 03 07:18:14 raspberrypi dockerd[496]:
> time="2020-11-03T07:18:14.064113743-08:00" level=warning msg="Your
> kernel does not support cgroup blkio throttle.w Nov 03 07:18:14
> raspberrypi dockerd[496]: time="2020-11-03T07:18:14.064249212-08:00"
> level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio
> throttle.r Nov 03 07:18:14 raspberrypi dockerd[496]:
> time="2020-11-03T07:18:14.064373483-08:00" level=warning msg="Your
> kernel does not support cgroup blkio throttle.w Nov 03 07:18:14
> raspberrypi dockerd[496]: time="2020-11-03T07:18:14.066367493-08:00"
> level=info msg="Loading containers: start." Nov 03 07:18:17
> raspberrypi dockerd[496]: time="2020-11-03T07:18:17.612685200-08:00"
> level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP
> address Nov 03 07:18:18 raspberrypi dockerd[496]:
> time="2020-11-03T07:18:18.710629367-08:00" level=info msg="Loading
> containers: done." Nov 03 07:18:20 raspberrypi dockerd[496]:
> time="2020-11-03T07:18:20.815943637-08:00" level=info msg="Docker
> daemon" commit=4484c46 graphdriver(s)=overlay2 v Nov 03 07:18:20
> raspberrypi dockerd[496]: time="2020-11-03T07:18:20.822947178-08:00"
> level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization" Nov 03 07:18:21
> raspberrypi systemd[1](https://www.docker.com/blog/happy-pi-day-docker-raspberry-pi/): Started Docker Application Container Engine.
> Nov 03 07:18:21 raspberrypi dockerd[496]:
> time="2020-11-03T07:18:21.273201136-08:00" level=info msg="API listen
> on /var/run/docker.sock"

**Update 1**

following [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40609248/530933) post i was able to get the server running it seems.  Editing docker.service file.  I now get a different error when trying to create

> C:\Users\oweng>docker-machine create --driver generic
> --generic-ip-address=192.168.1.2:2137 --generic-ssh-key "%HOMEPATH%/.ssh/id_rsa" --generic-ssh-user=pi remote-docker-host
> Running pre-create checks... Creating machine... (remote-docker-host)
> Importing SSH key... Waiting for machine to be running, this may take
> a few minutes... Error creating machine: Error waiting for machine to
> be running: Maximum number of retries (60) exceeded

**Update 2**
BMitch's comment lead me to these two tutorial which seem to be exactly what im trying todo
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/ssh
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/containers/choosing-dev-environment#_remote-machine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use `docker-machine` for that. Support for the tool seems to be going away, and there are much easier methods.

The easiest is to set `DOCKER_HOST` on your machine to be the ssh setting of the remote node:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=ssh://user@host
docker info # should now show the remote host if you have ssh access
```

If you find yourself changing between nodes a lot, I'd recommend setting up a context and then leaving DOCKER_HOST unset:

```
unset DOCKER_HOST
docker context create rpi --description "Pi" --docker "host=ssh://user@host"
docker --context rpi info
```

You can then make the context the new default with

```
docker context use rpi
```

And switch back to the local/default docker engine with

```
docker context use default
```

Comment: i feel like you might have swapped things a bit.  my docker host is raspbian/linux.  my deving machine is windows.  export isnt a windows command line command. however i setup an enviroment variable (DOCKER_HOST), VSCode picked up on that when i start it and asked to install remote explorer.  this has gotten me a little further, hopefully i can figure out the rest here.

Comment: @owengerig My own desktop is Linux so I tend to give Linux commands out of habit. You can use bash or WSL2 on Windows to run commands like export. Or use the Windows equivalent in cmd/powershell. The `docker context` commands will run regardless of environment.