# cAdvisor: How to run it with a remote docker API?

Tags: docker, containers, monitoring, devops, cadvisor

Is there a way to run a cAdvisor container in a Monitoring server and monitor docker containers in a separate server? Is there a command I can include when running cAdvisor?

Because I want to be able to monitor containers in a separate server but I’m not sure how to achieve that…

Any suggestions or shared knowledge would be very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: unfortunately it has to be installed on all servers and I think this is a big disadvantage of cadvisor

Comment: Yes this would have been greatly useful otherwise

Answer (score 2):

To take measurements from different machines, you will have to deploy `cAdvisor` to every separate server.

My source is:

> ### [A monitoring solution for Docker hosts, containers and containerized services](https://stefanprodan.com/2016/a-monitoring-solution-for-docker-hosts-containers-and-containerized-services/)
>
> #### Extending the monitoring system
>
> Dockprom Grafana dashboards can be easily extended to cover more then one Docker host. **In order to monitor more hosts**, all you need to do is to **deploy** a node-exporter and **a cAdvisor container on each host** and point the Prometheus server to scrape those.

On how to create and start a container by using the remote api, you can check this answer: [How to use docker remote api to create container?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31385589/1561148)